# Are WebRTC data channel packets atomic?

Tags: json, webrtc, rtcdatachannel

I want to use a WebRTC data channel to exchange json messages between peers.

Can I safely assume that each json message arrives atomically remotely (not like in TCP where packets may be split or chunked together) or do I need implement something like a length prefix to know where one message ends and another begin?

Using a reliable channel and possibly a tcp turn server, if that's relevant.

Comment: Yes, this is why we have APIs. Just because things are split up in lower level code doesn't mean the API has to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to the webRTC draft spec, whatever message you `send()` down a data channel should arrive in a single `onmessage` callback at the far end.

In real life however, Chrome sometimes calls `onmessage` with a partial message when it runs out of buffers. If you keep your messages <64k this seems not to happen.